# Powershell commad over .bat wont run

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run following command through Batch, but all I get is echo of the command.

```
PowerShell -command "&{Get-Content C:\temp\serversetup2\num.txt | Select-Object -Index 0 > num2.txt}"
```

Command runs well on PowerShell itself, but wont launch from batch

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Funny, but it also worked for me today. Yesterday it was struggling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand why you're using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for this task:

```batch-file
Set /P "$_=" 0< "C:\temp\serversetup2\num.txt" & ("%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /D/Q/V/C Echo !$_!) 1> "num2.txt"
```

But to do so, try it like this:

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile "Get-Content 'C:\temp\serversetup2\num.txt' | Select-Object -Index 0" 1> "num2.txt"
```

Or possibly this:

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile "Get-Content 'C:\temp\serversetup2\num.txt' | Select-Object -Index 0 | Set-Content 'num2.txt'"
```